# initialize submaps in std::map<..., boost::any>

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, boost

When initializing a `std::map<std::string, boost::any>`, the value `boost::any` can indeed take values of any type, including `std::map`s. However they need to be explicitly defined first, e.g.,

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <boost/any.hpp>
int main() {
  std::map<std::string, boost::any> a = {{"y", 2}};

  std::map<std::string, boost::any> any = {
    {"hh", 4},
    {"g", a}  // alright
  };
}
```

Trying the same thing implicitly, e.g.,

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <boost/any.hpp>
int main() {
  std::map<std::string, boost::any> any = {
    {"hh", 4},
    {"g", {{"y", 2}}}  // mööp
  };
}
```

results in the compile error

```
error: could not convert ‘{{"hh", 4}, {"g", {{"y", 2}}}}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::any>’
```

What's going wrong? Is there a way to fit the initialization into one statement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, the compiler can not know what type your initializer-list should eventually become.

Give him some help:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  using StringToAny = std::map<std::string, boost::any>;
  StringToAny any = {
    {"hh", 4},
    {"g", StringToAny{{"y", 2}}}  // jippie!
  };
}
```

Problem solved.

Comment: Good answer.  Regarding *"can not know what type"* - an example is that `{{"y", 2}}` - considered in isolation - could equally be a `vector` or `list` of `boost::any`.  It's interesting to contrast this with other languages where there's a distinct notation for creating associative containers on the fly (e.g. `{ "y" => 2 }` in Ruby, `{ "y": 2 }` in python), but that makes it hard to substitute another associative container - perhaps with better performance or memory utilisation for that specific use - without having to change all the client code.

Answer (score 6):

In general you brace-initialize `std::map<K, V>` like this:

```
std::map<K, V> m = {{k1, v1}, {k2, v2}, ...};
```

where `k1`, `k2`, *etc.* are used to initialize the keys, and `v1`, `v2`, *etc.* are used to initialize the mapped values.

Now we can see that in order to do what you are trying to do, it must be possible to initialize the mapped type `boost::any` from what you have in the position of `v2`, namely, `{{"y", 2}}`.

And this can't be done. You cannot do

```
boost::any a = {{"y", 2}};
```

therefore the way you're trying to initialize your map can't work either.

I see that this question is a follow-up question to another one you posted earlier today, and that you're coming from a Python background. Your background may lead you to believe that `{{"y", 2}}` represents a map by itself, the way that `{'y': 2}` is a dictionary literal in Python. However, this is not the case in C++; instead `{{"y", 2}}` has no type, and is not even an expression at all; it's a special syntactic category called a *braced-init-list*.

A *braced-init-list* can only be used for initialization. It is used to determine which constructor to use for initialization, and then its contents are passed to the chosen constructor. Trying to initialize a `boost::any` from a *braced-init-list* like this does not work, since the compiler has no way of deducing that you want to first convert `{{"y", 2}}` into a map and then wrap that map inside the `boost::any`.

The solution is to perform this conversion explicitly.

```
std::map<std::string, boost::any> any = {
  {"hh", 4},
  {"g", std::map<std::string, boost::any>{{"y", 2}} }
};
```